# Drools Spring with Jasper Report is causing CompilationResult conflict

Tags: java, spring, drools

Below dependency is for jasperreport

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
    <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
    <version>3.7.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Above dependency causes inclusion of `jdtcore` jar inclusion.

Then I have below dependency for drools-spring

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
    <artifactId>drools-spring</artifactId>
    <version>5.6.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

This includes `ecj` jar.

Now ecj and jdtcore has java files `org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.CompilationResult` with different versions and hence cause runtime exception.

How can I resolve these dependency conflict.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You either need to upgrade `jasperreport` version or if that's not possible then exclude the `jdtcore` and include the newer version of `jdtcore` as shown below:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
    <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
     <exclusions>
              <exclusion>
                   <groupId>eclipse</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jdtcore</artifactId>
              </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>eclipse</groupId>
    <artifactId>jdtcore</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0.v_658</version>
</dependency>
```

After this exclude `ecj` jar from drools-spring

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
    <artifactId>drools-spring</artifactId>
    <version>5.6.0.Final</version>
     <exclusions>
           <exclusion>
               <groupId>org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler</groupId>
               <artifactId>ecj</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

This will resolve the classes conflict

Answer (score 0):

For the above conflict I had to update the version of jdtcore version and exclude the ecj jar from drools. It worked for me this way.